# Diferença entre EXISTS e IN no postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu estou com uma dúvida que já pesquisei aqui, porém pra mim não fez nenhum sentido as explicações.

**Eu tenho essa query:**

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id IN (SELECT ID2 FROM b)
```

**E essa:**

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.ID = b.ID2).
```

Qual a diferença de resultado de ambos? O que pode acontecer em uma que não acontece na outra?

Também pode ser considerado o `NOT IN` e o `NOT EXISTS`.

o único tipo de resposta que vi, é que uma é mais performática que a outra, porém isso para mim é irrelevante.

Comment: Diria que a segunda opção é mais otimizada, pois não preciso montar uma coleção para verificar se o elemento está nela. O resultado final é o mesmo, mas a estratégia de solução pode não ser.

Comment: A alternativa utilizando IN pode levar a um resultado inesperado caso o resultado do subselect possa ser NULL. Como consta do manual: "As usual, null values in the rows are combined per the normal rules of SQL Boolean expressions. Two rows are considered equal if all their corresponding members are non-null and equal; the rows are unequal if any corresponding members are non-null and unequal; otherwise the result of that row comparison is unknown (null). If all the per-row results are either unequal or null, with at least one null, then the result of IN is null."

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que você tenha algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( id INTEGER, descricao TEXT );
CREATE TABLE b ( id2 INTEGER );

INSERT INTO a ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 1, 'alpha' );
INSERT INTO a ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 2, 'beta' );
INSERT INTO a ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 3, 'gamma' );
INSERT INTO a ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 4, 'delta' );

INSERT INTO b (id2) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b (id2) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b (id2) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO b (id2) VALUES (4);
```

**Na teoria**, a primeira *query* parece ser mais performática que a segunda, pois o `SELECT` contido dentro do `IN` seria executado apenas uma vez para se obter o universo de `IDs` contidos na tabela `b`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id IN (SELECT ID2 FROM b)
```

Ou:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

O `EXISTS` da segunda *query* vai depender do valor da coluna `ID` da tabela `a` para ser executado, ou seja, o `SELECT` na tabela `b` seria executado diversas vezes, uma para cada registro contido na tabela `a`, veja só:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.ID = b.ID2)
```

Ou:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE 1 = b.ID2) -- TRUE
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE 2 = b.ID2) -- FALSE
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE 3 = b.ID2) -- FALSE
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE 4 = b.ID2) -- TRUE
```

**Na prática**, o [planner/optimizer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/planner-optimizer.html) do`PostgreSQL` é *esperto* o bastante para compreender que ambas as *queries* produzem resultados idênticos, e *por baixo do panos* ambas as queries seriam executadas de forma idêntica.

Isso pode ser demonstrado com o comando [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-explain.html):

Primeira *Query*:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE id IN (SELECT ID2 FROM b)
```

Saída:

```
Hash Join  (cost=44.50..83.71 rows=615 width=36)
  Hash Cond: (a.id = b.id2)
  ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..22.30 rows=1230 width=36)
  ->  Hash  (cost=42.00..42.00 rows=200 width=4)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=40.00..42.00 rows=200 width=4)
              ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=4)
```

Segunda *Query*:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.ID = b.ID2)
```

Saída:

```
Hash Join  (cost=44.50..83.71 rows=615 width=36)
  Hash Cond: (a.id = b.id2)
  ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..22.30 rows=1230 width=36)
  ->  Hash  (cost=42.00..42.00 rows=200 width=4)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=40.00..42.00 rows=200 width=4)
              ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=4)
```

Na prática, não use a intuição, use o `EXPLAIN`!